# adding checkboxes to every cell infragistics ultragrid

Tags: checkbox, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I'm fairly new to infragistics and i need help -

i need to add a checkbox to every cell in my grid while still displaying the cell value and allow user to check/uncheck the cell-

for ex - my grid has many columns - text, datetime, numbers etc
each cell will display the text/date/number and also have a checkbox for user to check/uncheck that field

IS THIS POSSIBLE?

Comment: Yes is possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33485087/adding-a-checkbox-column-to-the-infragistics-ultrawingrid-that-is-bind-to-a-data

Comment: thanks steve but i dont want to add a column, i want to add a checkbox to each cell in every column, every row. IS THIS POSSIBLE???

Comment: Never seen something like that. Could you explain what is the purpose of this arrangement? Perhaps there is a different solution

Comment: I have an entity truck - im comparing 2 trucks and creating a 3rd truck based off these 2. im going to be selecting one row for every field:

for ex: my truck has color, height, length, numTires, make etc
i will display two rows - one for truck1, one for Truck2

user will want to select numTires from truck1, color from Truck2, height from truck1, length from truck2 etc.

Comment: do you think i need to try a completely different approach? i really dont want to

Comment: Not easy. You could add a checkbox column for every column and position it just before the referenced column. Then work on borders to make them appear as a single column. Or perhaps you could rotate your datasource to have a column with data from the first truck and a column with data fron the second one, adding just two checkboxes to choose.

Comment: nice idea!- but wont work for me bec of requirements - is there a way to do this with custom editors in every cell?

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to add an editor in the grid cells. For example, you can add UltraTextEditor with StateEditorButton (on the left or right as is better for your solution) in each cell like this:

```
private void UltraGrid_InitializeRow(object sender, InitializeRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.ReInitialize)
    {
        foreach (UltraGridCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            StateEditorButton checkBox = new StateEditorButton();
            UltraTextEditor textEditor = new UltraTextEditor();
            textEditor.ButtonsRight.Add(checkBox);

            cell.EditorComponent = textEditor;
            cell.Column.ButtonDisplayStyle = ButtonDisplayStyle.Always;
        } 
    }
}
```

Keep in mind this will add many editors to your grid - bad performance. Other possible solution is to add via [Creation Filter](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2012.2/CLR4.0/html/Win_Creation_Filter.html) the check boxes to your cells.
Either way the main question is - how you will save the checked state back to your data source? If you have a boolean column for each column you actually do not need to add any check boxes. So think how you will save this information.